# Looking for a Deadpool comic where Deadpool poses as Batman

Tags: story-identification, marvel, deadpool

I'm looking for a Deadpool comic issue (or one where he was featured in).

I remember a panel (quite big) where Deadpool tried to look like Batman, but in a funny way. He had cat ears, a sheet (?) as a cape and was posing like a gargoyle.

Anyone know this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you might be referring to the image below, which is an original piece of fanart by [Wil Woods](http://wil-woods.deviantart.com/art/Deadpool-The-Dead-Knight-Rises-427385881) titled "**The Dead Knight Rises**"

[image]

Comment: So,there isn't a comic issue, right?

Comment: No, just a single panel.

Comment: Yakkk.............looks creepy

Comment: This is the greatest work of art in all of human history